# How can I output a dictionary of arrays to a text file in from the immediate window in VS17?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

I am currently debugging a VB.NET program in Visual Studio and need to output a dictionary of arrays to a text file from the debugger. I have been trying to do this from the immediate window using the following:

`Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(StreamWriter(File.Create("test2.txt"), True), MyDictionary)`

Unfortunately, this is not working and is returning the error

`error BC30109: 'StreamWriter' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.`

Can anyone see why this is not working, or suggest an alternative approach?

Comment: What does *output a dictionary of [...] from the debugger* mean? Do you want to write to a text file the current content of a Dictionary? You can write this in code. Or implement a custom DebuggerVisualizer, to present the data object as you want, an/or log/store it, if that's a requirement. See: here a [DebuggerVisualizer implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61689162/7444103). This one is used to add a Visualizer for Images while debugging (adds a *magnifying glass* to Image object), but the object data can be anything else (except arrays and Object)

Comment: Btw, you need to create an instance of a StreamWriter.

Comment: To Jimi's comment, you could probably do this by using `New StreamWriter` in place of `StreamWriter`.  I'm not sure if you would then have issues with closure/cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

Why use the [Immediate window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/immediate-window?view=vs-2019), the Immediate window is used to debug and evaluate expressions.

If you want to write the contents of a dictionary into a text file, you can try the following code:

```
Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(path)
        For Each entry As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In MyDictionary
              sw.WriteLine("[{0} {1}]", entry.Key, entry.Value)
        Next
End Using
```