# Can't escape from ToolStripTextBox in a particular case

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

It is hard to describe the issue. Let me illustrate it with a very simple example.
Start from a new solution of winform(.net framework 4.8).
Add a menustrip with a textbox, then a datagridview.
And let's handle KeyDown event of datagridview.

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F3)
    toolStripTextBox1.Focus();
```

Ok, now we start the program.

1. Click the datagridview to focus on it.
2. Click the textbox to change focus.
3. Press Esc on your keyboard.

You can see that the datagridview gets the focus as expected.

But if you make a little change in step two, the result will be confusing.​ Press F3 instead of clicking the textbox.​ When you press Esc this time, the focus is just lost.​ I tried to print the name and the handle of focused control. It turned out to be the textbox itself.​ Can somebody explain it?

Comment: If you set the focus to the ToolStripItem like that, the Control that is focused is the underlying TextBox, hence the handle of this Control is what - internally - is defined as the `Hwnd That Lost Focus`. The handle of the Control that loses the focus when a ToolStripItem is first clicked, is the target handle where the focus is restored when the ESC key is pressed. So, when you press ESC in that context, the Focus is set to the underlying TextBox, but the TooStripManager renders the ToolStripItem as if the focus was moved.

Comment: You can use reflection to restore the value of the Field that stores the handle of the Control that lost the Focus (your DataGridView here). The ToolStrip's Field name is `hwndThatLostFocus`. It's `private`, so set the BindingFlags to `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.SetField` -- As a note, the F3 key usually handles the Columns order in a DataGridView (as clicking on the Column Header). Of course F3 is also used to trigger a search function, but could be *confusing* here.

Comment: In fact, I could add an event handler of textbox's Leave to fix this. `private void toolStripTextBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e){dataGridView1.Focus();}` But I still wonder what is the difference between these two cases(mouse clicking and shortcuts).

Comment: And F3 could be changed to any button, there is no difference if you use another key. Just ensure the datagridview is readonly if you want to use a key like `Keys.A`.

Comment: If you hard-code a Control in the Leave event of the ToolStripItem, you cannot use the `TAB` / `SHIFT +TAB` keys to move between Items in a ToolStrip. This behavior is also (explicitly) handled internally. You should probably manage this new behavior at the Form level (the Parent notifies the Control that loses focus). If you just need to handle this for a single Control, as mentioned, you can set `[ToolStrip].GetType().GetField("hwndThatLostFocus", [BindingFlags]).SetValue([ToolStrip], dataGridView1.Handle);` after the focus is moved. `[BindingFlags]` are the flags mentioned before.

Answer (score 1):

Now I'm quite sure it is some kind of bug. After Jimi's mention of `hwndThatLostFocus`, I had traced this variable for several hours. Although I failed to locate the exact position where `hwndThatLostFocus` was changed, something unreasonable was found: when `Focus()` was called in different cases, the result lost consistency.

Under most circumstances, if `Focus()` of ToolStripTextBox is called, `hwndThatLostFocus` of ToolStripTextBox will be set to 0, just like the example in my question. But if you click the datagridview and click the ToolStripTextBox and then click the datagridview agian, this time you call `Focus()`, `hwndThatLostFocus` will remain a pointer to the datagridview. In addition, this could be reproduced in .net 6.

Later I will report this to Microsoft. For now, there are three ways to avoid this.

1. Simulate a mouse click by `SetCursorPos` and `mouse_event` in `user32.dll`.
2. Use reflection like Jimi's advice.
3. Override `ProcessCmdKey` in `Form`, and take care of `Keys.Escape` yourself:

   ```
   protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
   {
       if (keyData == Keys.Escape && msg.HWnd == toolStripTextBox1.TextBox.Handle)
       {
           dataGridView1.Focus();
           return true;
       }
       return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
   }
   ```

As I avoid using unnecessary reflect, and Dllimport is also some kind of ugly to me, I prefer the third one.

Comment: This is hard to fix, since the ToolStripManager needs to handle a large number of different components and possible states, including all types of menus, so the behaviors it can handle must be limited to the standard (it's also complicated not to break existing code). You can see here: [Debugger Visualizer Winform ToolStripDropDownMenu ComboBox only shows items when first shown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61689162/7444103) another *misbehavior*, which spreads as a virus to the entire System after a while. You should try and to indulge its whims.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand the difficulty of fixing these aged and low-level bugs. Changing them could be accompanied by some new issues. Like a seesaw, you press one side of it down, another comes up. The report is just a try. Who knows? Maybe they will fix it another day. Until the day comes, the third approach will satisfy me. Thanks for all of your advice.